# Changing object types in C#, or workaround

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to optimize my code and I have a method that I would like to populate the drop downs for a viewmodel depending on which type of viewmodel is supplied to the method.  The reason I'm doing this is to reduce redundant code.

I realize I am thinking about this problem in a javascript way, so I think I am making this harder than it needs to be.

Here's the pseudo-code, which doesn't work because you can't change types in C# from what I understand:

What would be the be the best way to solve this problem?

**EDIT** Added code from ViewModel to clarify my question.
I am trying to call the same method from two different controller methods, and provide the common selectlists for the dropdown menus in each.

Here is the common code from the viewmodels:

```
[Display(Name = "What kind of Stuff?")]
public int? StuffId { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StuffTypes { get; set; }
```

Here is the code from the Controller:

```
private void populateDropDownsPart2(Part2ViewModel part2viewmodel, PrintViewModel printviewmodel)
    {
       var currentviewmodel = (some initialization object);

        if (part2viewmodel == null)
        {
            currentviewmodel = printviewmodel;

        }
        else
        {
           currentviewmodel = part2viewmodel;

        }

        var SomeDropDownContent = new SelectList(db.Stuff, "StuffId", "StuffName", studentmeddiet.StuffId);
        currentviewmodel.SelectListOfStuff = SomeDropDownContent;
    }
```

Here is the common code from the different views:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StuffId, Model.StuffTypes,"--Select--",new {name="StuffId" })
```

Comment: If both types have common information, then create an interface or parent class and use that as the model type. By the way, that code is very "Web Formsy". Keep in mind that in MVC you pass the model to the view which is typically built with a templating engine like Razor.

Comment: This is hardly optimizing your code, only making it inflexible. Why not a  method that returns typeof `SelectList` and then in the controller methods, `viewModel.SelectListOfStuff = GetMySelectList();`

Comment: Mason, I have updated the code to include the Model & View Code, and specified that the code from the original question is from the controller, I like the sound of the interface.  To Stephen's point, I have about 24 dropdown menus to populate so I was hoping to achieve what you suggest, but some viewmodels only use maybe 2 or 3 of the select lists, but the print viewmodel uses ALL of the dropdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a pure design perspective, you would want an interface:

```
public interface ISelectableListOfStuff
{
    SelectList SelectListOfStuff;
}
```

Any view model that you want this method to work on, should implement that interface:

```
public Part2ViewModel : ISelectableListOfStuff
```

Then your method should take an ISelectableListOfStuff:

```
private void populateDropDownsPart2(ISelectableListOfStuff selectableViewModel)
```

You can call that method and pass in any object of a type that implements the `ISelectableListOfStuff` interface.

Comment: Why would you pollute by view by generating the `SelectList` in the view as opposed to in the controller?

Comment: @StephenMuecke separate responsibilities. The view model should contain the data, the view decides how it will be displayed. A HTML select element "data" is generally just key value pairs (should be in the view model). The View might decide things like what to call the select element, what classes it will have.

Comment: Exactly, which is why the controller should be responsible for the generating the data to display in the dropdown not the view, so in the view its simply `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeProperty. Model.SelectListOfStuff)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke but then you're making the decision in the controller that the view has a dropdown.
What if the designer chooses to use radio buttons? or checkboxes?

Although I guess SelectList makes sense in those cases. From the description of the class: "Represents a list that lets users select one item."

Comment: A `SelectList` is for a dropdown, and makes no sense for checkboxes or radio buttons or any other type of control

Comment: A SelectList would make sense for a set of Radio buttons. "Represents a list that lets users select one item.".
A MultiSelectList would make sense for a set of Checkboxes.
"Represents a list of items that users can select more than one item from."
If SelectList is only for Dropdown, then it should be up to the View to create it.

Comment: Sorry, but no it does not. For example how would `SelectList` be applicable in radio buttons `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Male") @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Female")`?

Comment: I would expect the designer to create a custom editor template.
The `SelectList` just implies there is a set of data and only 1 item selected. Although reading more into the documentation it seems to tie itself to a dropdown. - The controller and view model should not be making decisions about how the data will be displayed.

Comment: I have updated my poorly asked question to specify what my Model, Controller and View code look like.